# Any way to reply to a bunch of people in the comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I've posted a question and 4-5 people have given me good pointers, and I went back and tried to work on their pointers. It does not work as I expected, Now I want to reply to all in one comment saying that I tried this this this and it did not work. Why does SO stop me from doing that?

Comment: Because you should not be able to spam everyone in a comment thread; by limiting you to *one* name per comment you are also rate limited by the 'at least 15 seconds between comments' rule.

Comment: You could edit the question to add the various ideas and the results. That would make the question more complete.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You have a very good point. But, If i have to spam, I'd create multiple comments anyhow. that would be a good feature from my point of view.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [@PatriciaShanahan's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267922/any-way-to-reply-to-a-bunch-of-people-in-the-comments#comment73455_267922) to your question: you should edit your question to reflect the solutions you tried and the results of those attempts. This helps future visitors understand the problem better.

Providing feedback to individual users can be useful, but what you really want is to ask the community for additional help, which is what questions are for.

Comment: Note also that an edit will bump the question back up to the front page, so it will still get exposure after the edit

Answer (score 2):

I think this might stem from a misunderstanding as to what purpose comments serve.

They're second-class citizens, only really meant as a way to gain more information/insight into the problem, as opposed to a lite forum in which one is going back and forth with others, giving feedback/info on the question.

Your question should be able to stand *alone*, and this includes anything new that you've tried that's been exposed in the comments through requests for clarification.